# Anime in which a little girl finds a school where they reanimate constructs from dead things to fight

Tags: story-identification, anime

i remember only one of the first episodes. There is a little girl who is either lost or running from something in the woods when she stumbles into a really big building that turns out to be a school, but it's no ordinary school. One of the teachers thinks that the girl is a transfer/new student that they were expecting, but never showed up, and bring her inside where she finds out the school creates a (I don't wanna say robot but like a robot) living thing from dead things and makes them fight. I also remember there is a graveyard episode where they have to dig up something and make it into one of their creations.

It is also in, I think, a more "realistic" anime art style.

Comment: I recommend trying the prompts at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to [edit] more details into your question. Like did you watch this on VHS? DVD? Laserdisc? YouTube? Netflix?